# Google Colab taking too long to train a GAN

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, generative-adversarial-network

I followed the Generative-Adversarial Network tutorial on the TensorFlow site (linked below), it says "This may take about one minute / epoch with the default settings on Colab.". So far only two epochs have completed with each being around 750 seconds. That means it will take 10 hours to complete all 50 epochs. I tried first with default settings, then tried with TPU selected and if anything it now is worse. I am hoping to find anything wrong on my end which could help speed up the training of the GAN.

The code is too long to put here so I'm putting the link to my walkthrough of the tutorial down below.

Link to the tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan

Link to my Google Colab code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10-VTSyFqWMRT3NIWOU77he7li4YRE0dY

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adjusting the 'runtime type' to GPU in the Runtime menu?